# Required characteristics of particles or forces that support 'psychic phenomena'

Tags: forces, particle-physics, experimental-physics, interactions

In Sean Carroll's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01ENXQY1S), *The
Big Picture: On the Origins of Life, Meaning, and the Universe Itself*, pg. 156, he talks about how 'psychic phenomena' like moving objects using mind power is not compatible with the laws of physics. The particles & forces we know don't have the capability of supporting such phenomena.

He then went on to say

> We know that there aren't new particles or forces out there yet to be discovered that would support them (psychic phenomena). Not simply because we haven't found them yet, but because we definitely would have found them if they had the right characteristics to give us the requisite powers.

What exactly does he mean by the 'right characteristics' of these new particles or forces? Why would we have definitely found them if they existed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A substantial observable characteristic of a particle is what it interacts with/can decay into. Carroll of course takes a materialist viewpoint here where particles that "support psychic phenomena" should be able to interact with our brain (or body) matter at ordinary, every-day energy levels.

But our meat consists of protons, neutrons and electrons, and we've done enough experiments (in colliders and otherwise) with these to be as certain as we can be that there is no relevant unknown interaction with an additional particle species for these particles at low energy levels, because we would have produced these additional particles in our collider experiments. Even if we could not detect them, we would notice "missing" energy/momentum after the collisions, much like how we figured out neutrinos must exist without being able to directly detect them.